# power automate from shared mailbox to sharepoint library

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, power-automate

I need to know best practices for a power uatomate flow that will copy incoming emails to a SP library.
To avoid having the WF associated with a person's account (that might leave etc), is it still good practice to have a system account with a license running the WF? What about the notifications of failures? is it possible to send them to the site owners?

Comment: Check my answer below, and tell me if you need more clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it's not recommended for business scenarios to associate a certain Workflow with Person's account, so working with some sort of a "**Service Account**" is for sure a best practice,

However, lately after the last licensing updates, you should consider this following scenario : after a while of using this Service Account for Power Automate, you will have for sure a lot of flows with a lof of connectors,

So from a licensing point of view (and not performance point of view) : with new licensing changes coming into effect, there will be new throttling limits for number of request a particular acocunt can make via Flow and if one service account  is used for all cases, it would surely hit that throttling limit.

You can refer to this links :

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerapps-flow-licensing-faq
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/api-request-limits-allocations

**For the notifications :**

it’s best to configure Flows to email an email distribution group that will then deal with these failures. The Flow service account email should also forward emails to the same distribution group, as other important information about the account may appear that would otherwise be missed by the staff who are managing the Flows. You can do that view Exchange Online by defining a rule to forward Power Automate emails to a distribution group.

So in recap :

1. You should work with a Service Account
2. You should consider licensing limits
3. Don't forget to configure email forwarding to a distribution group

I hope I answered your question correctly.

Comment: If I use a service account licensed specifically for this job, I should have no problem, isn't it?

Comment: Yeap, that's exactly what I have done so far in my Organization

Answer (score 2):

Using a service account to create a flow is common best practice in your use case.

If you don't have license constraint, and the mailbox whose incoming email count it large, then you can should not use the same service account in other flows to
avoid the daily threshold limit hit of actions.

Based on the incoming mail count and number of actions in your flow, you need to decide the [licensing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerapps-flow-licensing-faq).

**Send Email to Site Owners**

You can use the Send HTTP Action to SharePoint, Scope and Run After to achieve the requirement.

Use REST API in the Send HTTP Action to SharePoint action to get the site owner's email.

Scope allows you to contain the other actions inside it. So you can club all the actions in which you think the error can occur in the single scope action.

Then configure the run after property of the send email action to run if scope has failed or timed out, Hence, if there are any error in any of your action added inside the scope, it will send an email to site owners.

**References:**

1. [Send an HTTP request to SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#send-an-http-request-to-sharepoint)
2. [Configure run after option](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/error-handling/2-configure-run-after)

[image]